# Youtube's categories horizontal listview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I want to implement in an App a horizantal selectable list of categories, exactly like the one seen on youtube. But I have no idea how youtube does it. I mean is it a tablayout, or or just a recyclerview. The images below shows the feature.

[image: The highlighted list[1]]

Comment: I think you should go with `recyclerview` or you can also use [Chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right with material chips.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement both way, using **custom tablayout** as well as using **horizontal recyclerview**. Custom tablayout is little bit difficult to implement. But horizontal recyclerview will be better choice and it's easier to put any custom view inside recyclerview and upon selecting any option, just notify the adapter using notifyDataSetChanged method and load data in vertical recyclerview.